# zero padding a signal in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an audio signal of length 12769. I'm trying to perform STFT on it by breaking it into small windows of 1024 samples. This gives me with 12 exact windows while there are 481 points remaining. Since i need 543 (1024 - 481) more points to make up 1024 samples, i used the following code to zero pad.

```
f = [a zeros(1,542)];
```

where `a` is the audio file.
However i get an error saying

??? Error using ==> horzcat

CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Your vector `a` is a column vector and cannot be concatenated  with row vector `zeros(1,542)`. Use `zeros(542,1)` instead.
However, it is much easier to just use

```
f = a;
f(1024*ceil(end/1024)) = 0;
```

MATLAB will zero pad the vector up to element 1024, and it is independent of the array being column or row.

Comment: When I use the code you've mentioned

f = a;
f(1024) = 0;

The length of a is still the same, which is 12769. Shouldn't it be changed to 13312.

Comment: Should be `f = a;` `f(length(a)+542) = 0;`. Easier? I don't think so. Faster? Maybe. Harder to read and understand? Definitely.

Comment: @user2482542 I corrected that. Now it zero pads to the next multiple of 1024.

Answer (score -1):

You can either remove the excess 481 samples using

```
Total_Samples = length(a);
for i=1 : Total_Samples-481
    a_new[i] = a[i];
```

or you could add an additional 543 Zero samples by using

```
Total_Samples = length(a);
for i=Total_Samples+1 : Total_Samples+543
    a[i] = 0 ;
```

Comment: Ok. So does the last line imply that zeros are added for the remaining 543 points?? Because you haven't mentioned anything about zeros, so wondering

Comment: Sorry I have edited the code. Now it adds 543 Zeros from the 12770th samples. Therefore, Samples from 12770 to 13312 samples are Zeros.

Comment: No need to use loops for this!